# Specifying steps in y-axis of Pandas plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use the following plot function to create a line chart of a Pandas dataframe

```
row = df.iloc[0].astype(int)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
row.plot(marker='o', fontsize=20, ylabel=yax_label)
plt.show()
```

Problem is that, the y steps are shown in float (0.5 steps). Is there any way to control that? For example, 3,4,5,6,7 as integers.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `xticks` \ `yticks` parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.set_yticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html?highlight=set_yticks#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-yticks):

*(I can't run your code, send an example)*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axe = plt.subplots(1, 3, constrained_layout=True)

axe[0].plot(range(10))
axe[0].set_yticks(np.arange(0,10,0.5))

axe[1].plot(range(10))
axe[1].set_yticks(np.arange(0,10))

axe[2].plot(range(10))
axe[2].set_yticks(np.arange(0,10,2))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]